# Django ModelForm get next item in list after submit

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm not really too sure how to title this question, but I'm trying to develop a simple webapp with Django. What I'm trying to do is that the user will manually tag each image, and each tag will have a foreign key to a specific image (but each image can have multiple tags). The index page is supposed to display the actual image, but I haven't figured that out yet...

Pretty much the problem is, I'm not sure how to implement it so for each page, the index page will show a picture and a box for the image tag. After the user submits, it will go to the next untagged image / image with the least number of tags. Right now, the user can submit a tag (and the data is written correctly), but it still stays on the same image. I'm a Python / Django noob, so forgive me :P

Here is the relevant source code:

forms.py:

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Image.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class Meta:
    model = Tag
```

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
image_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
num_tags = models.IntegerField(default=0)   
image_score = models.FloatField()   
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%d' % self.id 

class Tag(models.Model):
image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
tag_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.tag_text
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponse(request.POST['image'])

    image = Image.objects.all()[0]
    form = InputForm(initial={'image': image})
    return render_to_response('imageSite/index.html',
    {
            'form':form,
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def submit(request):
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    if(form.is_valid()):
            image = form.cleaned_data['image'];
            image.num_tags = image.num_tags + 1
            image.save()
            model = form.save()
            model.save()
            return redirect(index)
```

index.html:

```
<ul>
<form action="/imageSite/submit/" method="post">
{%csrf_token %}
<table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
</table>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `return redirect(index)` won't work. You'll need to return a redirect response with the proper URL to which it should redirect. For example:

```
redirect_url = '/images/45/'
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

See [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) in the Django documentation for a full example. Note that the value for `redirect_url` needs to be computed in your view: you'll need to compute the `Image` object with the least number of tags and use Django's [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) to cleanly compute the URL of that `Image` object. If the form is invalid then you should not perform a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I figured another way to do it; basically I just grab the element in the QuerySet with the least amount of tags, and display it with the form.